# Azure SDK for .NET (VS2013) 2.5 requires Visual Studio 2013 update 3 or later

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

I wanted to install Azure 2.5 SDK for VS 2013 and that required updating VS 2013 to Update 3 or later. Update 4 was the recommended one so I installed it.  Azure 2.5 SDK installation still broke at the same spot. When I checked about dialog in VS 2013 it said that my current version is 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 but my Extensions and Updates feature still offers me Update 4. When I select this update,Extensions and Updates window says that my current version is 12.0.21005.1 and new version will be the one mentioned above, 12.0.31101.00. Anyone had this kind of issue? Should I install some other version of Azure SDK?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Which Edition of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure SDK 2.5.1](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/downloads/archive-net-downloads/) was released in March 2015.  Along with support for Visual Studio 2015 Update 4 this release also updated the SDK for recent changes in the Azure Platform:

- Azure Websites was renamed to Azure App Service.
- Azure API Apps (Preview) support has been added.
- The Websites node in Server Explorer has been deprecated.
- Azure Mobile Apps (Preview) support has been added
- Add > Azure API App Client gesture now supports local Swagger JSON files
- Web App and API App publishing dialogs have been enhanced
- Azure API App Server Explorer nodes provide links to the API Apps

There are a few [known issues](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-release-notes/#known_issues_2_5_1), so make sure you read those before you jump in.